# Making :focus work in ie7 using css?

Tags: css, forms, internet-explorer-7, focus

Is there a simple hack for this? I'd prefer to avoid javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case JavaScript is the simple hack. Take a look at the [ie7-js project](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/).

> IE7.js is a JavaScript library to make
>   Microsoft Internet Explorer behave
>   like a standards-compliant browser. It
>   fixes many HTML and CSS issues and
>   makes transparent PNG work correctly
>   under IE5 and IE6.

Upgrade MSIE5.5-7 to be compatible with MSIE8.

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<script src="http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/version/2.1(beta4)/IE8.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

You can also refer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/967715/ie7-inputfocus). [IE7 doesn't support this pseudo class](http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/IE7#IE7_Compatibility_List_Support_Test).

Answer (score 5):

IE6/7 don't support any `:focus`

You can use this jQuery snippet, to handle `:focus` for them:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $(".block div").bind('focus blur',function(){$(this).toggleClass('focus')});
});
```

The usage:

```
.block div:focus { background: #ccc; } /* For all browser, except IE6/7 */
.block div.focus { *background: #ccc; } /* For IE6/7 */
```

You should repeat all styles for `:focus` on new line. And don't forget about star hack - *

Answer (score 2):

For ie6 you can use :active but ie7 you need javascript