# How are inputs, links, buttons, etc able to turn that fuzzy blue color?

Tags: css, keyboard, navigation

This may be a dumb question, but that fuzzy blue color that you get when focusing on stuff? Yeah, the one I'm getting when focused on this `textarea` right now. I'm guessing it's a browser thing, but I want to know: what causes this?

More importantly, I notice that when <kbd>TAB</kbd>-bing around my own web app, **this does not happen**. What am I doing to cause this behavior to break, or alternately, what can I do to enable this behavior on my own site?

**EDIT**: There seems to be confusion about exactly what behavior I'm referring to, so here it is:

[image]

Comment: Where have you seen that, you can point out a link to that?

Comment: In this comment box, for example. Click to add a comment, and the `textarea` should turn blue. Note that this may depend on your browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In css, the style of an input can be set with ':focus'.
Take a look at this page for further information: [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/pr_pseudo_focus.asp).
A browser can have a default stylesheet, which can result in the blue color you are referring to.

Answer (score 1):

### [See Working Example](http://jsbin.com/apaxa5)

---

You can achieve similar effect like this:

```
input:focus, textarea:focus, select:focus
{
  border:1px solid #fafafa;
  -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 6px #007eff;
  -moz-box-shadow:0 0 5px #007eff;
  box-shadow:0 0 5px #007eff;
}
```

As can be seen, it creates that effect with CSS3 and proprietary CSS styles. **That will only work in modern browsers that support CSS3.**

Comment: I'm glad to see a working example, but this doesn't answer why `<a>` tags, for example, have the effect naturally on so many websites.

Comment: @Josh Smith: Links do not have same effect, they have blue outline which you can disable with CSS like this: `a{outline:none;}`

Comment: I don't get the blue outline at all by default. Weird. Any thoughts as to why?

Comment: @Josh Smith: That doesn't come in all browsers. You can check it it FF 3+ or IE7+. And it shows up when you press Tab key to reach at a link or focus it in some other way.

Answer (score 0):

Under MSIE 8 and 9, `:focus` requires one of the following doctypes:

- HTML4 Strict: `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">`
- HTML5: `<!DOCTYPE html>`

It produces no effect with one of the following doctypes:

- HTML4 Transitional: `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">`
- no doctype specified

Under MSIE 7 (and most probably 6 but I did not test), `:focus` does not work and requires a Javascript+CSS hack, see [IE7 input:focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/967715/ie7-inputfocus)