# inline div issue in ie7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

I've created a simple widget in JQuery that wraps texboxes in a div, adds a clear text button and a placeholder. Added the main bits for this at http://jsfiddle.net/BpkDN/, something in the CSS which I can't find is messing the styling up in ie7. Seems to work in every other version.

Here is an extract of what my widget produces:

CSS:

```
 ::-ms-clear {
      display: none;
  }
.jui-textbox {
    border: 1px solid #DADADA;
    position: relative;
    padding:0 !important;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 33px;
    line-height: 33px;
    display: inline-block;
    *display:inline;
    margin: 10px 0;

}

.jui-textbox input {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #313131;
    height: 33px !important;
    line-height:33px\9;
    width: 300px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;  
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 5px !important;
    border: none;
    float:left;
}

.jui-textbox-placeholder {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;  
    color: #A1A1A1;
    height: 33px;
    line-height: 33px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    left: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: text;
}


.jui-textbox-hover {
    border: 1px solid #CACACA;
}
.jui-textbox-active {
    border: 1px solid #a1a1a1;
}

.jui-textbox-clear.show{
    display:inline-block !important;
    *display:inline !important; 
}
.jui-textbox-clear {
    display:none;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #fff;
    border-left: 1px solid #a1a1a1;
    width: 33px;
    height: 33px;
    background-image:url(icons/x.png);
    background-position:center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;    
}
.jui-hoverable:hover,.jui-hoverable-hovered
{   background-color: #f1f1f1;}

textarea:focus, input:focus{
    outline: none;
}
```

Html

```
<div class="jui-textbox">
    <div class="jui-textbox-placeholder" unselectable="on" style="font-size: 14px;">                                                
           Default
    </div>
    <input type="text" style="width: 300px;">
    <div class="jui-textbox-clear jui-hoverable jui-icons-x"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What's happening to the style?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**CSS:**

```
 ::-ms-clear {
      display: none;
  }
.jui-textbox {
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid #DADADA;
    position: relative;
    padding:0 !important;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 33px;
    line-height: 33px;
    display: inline-block;
    /**display:inline;*/
    margin: 10px 0;
}

.jui-textbox input {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #313131;
    height: 33px !important;
    line-height:33px\9;
    width: 300px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;  
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 5px !important;
    border: none;
    float:left;
}

.jui-textbox-placeholder {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;  
    color: #A1A1A1;
    height: 33px;
    line-height: 33px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    left: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: text;
}


.jui-textbox-hover {
    border: 1px solid #CACACA;
}
.jui-textbox-active {
    border: 1px solid #a1a1a1;
}

.jui-textbox-clear.show{
    display:inline-block !important;
    *display:inline !important; 
}
.jui-textbox-clear {
    display:none;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #fff;
    border-left: 1px solid #a1a1a1;
    width: 33px;
    height: 33px;
    background-image:url(icons/x.png);
    background-position:center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;   
}
.jui-hoverable:hover,.jui-hoverable-hovered
{   background-color: #f1f1f1;}

textarea:focus, input:focus{
    outline: none;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="jui-textbox">
        <div class="jui-textbox-placeholder" unselectable="on" style="font-size: 14px;">
                Default
        </div>
        <input type="text" style="width: 300px;">
        <div class="jui-textbox-clear jui-hoverable jui-icons-x"></div>
    </div>
    <br/>
<div class="jui-textbox">
        <div class="jui-textbox-placeholder" unselectable="on" style="font-size: 14px;">
                 Focused
        </div>
        <input type="text"  style="width: 266px;">
        <div class="jui-textbox-clear jui-hoverable jui-icons-x show"></div>
</div>
```

**Tested in IE7 (Vista).**

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/PENFT/

Another solution, but it's not very clean:

- Removing `width` from `.jui-textbox`.
- Adding `float:left;` to `".jui-textbox"` and changing `<br/>` with `<br
  style="clear:both"` />.

**Note:** `<br style="clear:both" />` its so dirty.

Comment: Ah this seems to narrow things down, so setting the container to inline causes the issue in ie7. Is there any way to achieve this without setting the width of .jui-textbox explicitly ? I'd rather it rely on the input for that. If not this may have to be the solution for now!

Comment: You can add "float:left;" in ".jui-textbox", and force element to self-clear its children.

Comment: Taking these 2 solutions in consideration ill go with your first suggestion and just set the width of the container in my widget code seeing as I create it there anyway. Cheers for the help!

Answer (score 0):

In this case JavaScript is the simple hack, because in IE7 :focus doesn't work. Take a look at the [ie7-js project](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/).

> IE7.js is a JavaScript library to make
>   Microsoft Internet Explorer behave
>   like a standards-compliant browser. It
>   fixes many HTML and CSS issues and
>   makes transparent PNG work correctly
>   under IE5 and IE6.

Upgrade MSIE5.5-7 to be compatible with MSIE8.

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<script src="http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/version/2.1(beta4)/IE8.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

You can also refer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/967715/ie7-inputfocus). [IE7 doesn't support this pseudo class](http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/IE7#IE7_Compatibility_List_Support_Test).

Comment: I'm afraid the issue isn't to do with focusing I simply put up a static example of my widget states. The issue is how that html is displayed in ie7 with my current CSS. Nevertheless I will checkout that project , looks interesting!